# Preventing a rotated CGAffineTransform from being wrecked by view autorotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I have a subclass of a UIImageView containing some gesture recognisers that I'm using to apply transforms to itself.  I'm having no issues with panning or scaling, but the rotated transform is causing problems when the device itself is rotated.  Basically each time the device is rotated it will have the effect of scaling the image...

I guess it makes sense that the rotation of everything might cause problems with a rotated transform but does anyone know any ways around this kind of behaviour?  Preferably something that can be implemented within the UIImageView subclass?  I need other sibling views to autoresize so I can't disable "autoresize subviews" in the parent view.

Here's the code responsible for creating the rotated transform if it helps:

```
- (void)setUpRotation
{
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *newRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotationGesture)];
    newRecognizer.delegate = self;
    self.rotationRecognizer = newRecognizer;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:self.rotationRecognizer];
    [newRecognizer release];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)handleRotationGesture
{
    // Initial state
    if(self.rotationRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {        
        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - self.rotationRecognizer.rotation);    
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transform;
    self.transform  = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);  

    lastRotation = self.rotationRecognizer.rotation; 
}
```

This is on iOS 5.0 btw.